# How to calculate noise resistent mean on discrete data?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am at the moment struggling with a problem which brings me kind of headache.
My situation:
I have got some thousand of regions. Each region contains around 500 values. These values are all lying for sure in [0,255].
I want to merge/cluster these regions fully automatically by comparing their mean. 
Merging works well and does what it has to do. However I encountered some problems when the data is quite noisy.
Because a few really high noise values will shift the mean too far away to cluster my values correctly.
Another problem is that the method to use should run quite fast on normal computers.
That is why I thought of some kind of "weighted mean" which weights the numbers higher which lie in the same region.

To be more specific, one example:

```
1. Example values (only a few to illustrate my idea):
Data: {1,1,1,1,251}
Mean: 51
```

Compared to the other regions which only contain a small amount of noise (e.g. {1,1,1,1,51} --> Mean: 11) this region will definititvely be clustered/merged with other regions wrongly.
A better value for my first example would be a value less than 20 (it is not important to guarantee any upper or lower bound).

My current idea is to use a histogram for estimating the probability density on a fast way.
So what I do is dividing my value range [0,255] to 64 equalsized "bins".

```
Bin 1: Values from 0 to 3
Bin 2: Values from 4 to 7
...
```

Then I am iterating over all numbers and put them into the bins. After I put all values into the bins, I am sorting the bins on this way that the bin containing the most elements is the first one.
After sorting I am calculating a weighted mean whereby the bin with the most elements gets the weight 1 and every bin afterwards gets half the weight of the bin before.
E.g.

```
Bin X: 
- Mean: 250
- Count of Elements: 10

Bin Y: 
- Mean: 15
- Count of Elements: 5

Bin Z: 
- Mean: 0
- Count of Elements: 1
```

Then I would calculate the weighted mean as:

```
(250+15/2+0/4)/(1+0.5+0.25) = 147.142857143
```

This solution is kind of "ok" as long as I am having one peak for one of my bins. However when I have something like that:

```
Bin X: 
- Mean: 250
- Count of Elements: 10

Bin Y: 
- Mean: 14
- Count of Elements: 10
```

It would be asewome to get something around the real mean (= 132).
However my method would return: 171.333

Overall this approach runs quite fast on my computer but it is still much slower than calculating the mean.
I also thought about using median however median reveals really big problem when my values look like this:

Data: {1,1,1,1,251,251}

As Median would be 1, but the "wished" outcome would be something near to 80 (Mean: 101).

So what I am basically searching for is a method to weight similar values which occur quite often a bit more than values which do not occur very often.
However the weighting should not be too large or too small.

I also thought about using formulars like similar to the generalized mean (= Hölder mean). However these formulars will only weight big or small values higher but not these values which are similar and occur quite often.

So my basic question is:
Can you think of any formular which is quite fast to calculate and still is quite noise resistent. 
However I do not need any guarantees or exact calculations (as I am also not possible to tell which value I exactly want). 
I only want to shift the mean nearer to these values which occur quite often and are quite similar.

Comment: as always in signal processing, it depends on the model you choose/have for the noise. in the case of i.i.d. gaussian additive noise, the maximum likelihood estimator is the trivial mean.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to reduce my noise to any kind of model. It could be Salt & Pepper noise but also Gaussian, poisson or even something "totaly strange". That is why I am not searching for any perfect solution but for a solution which helps me weighting the more frequently values higher.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly-well established and well-studied possibility is to use a
**trimmed mean**. It wouldn't work well with small sets like the
5-number sets you give as examples, but I assume you usually have
more numbers.

A 5% trimmed mean is computed as follows. Sort the data, throw
out the bottom 5% and the top 5% and average the remaining 90%.
In R statistical software, this possibility is included as an
option in the `mean` function.

You can look at the Wikipedia article on this subject, where the terminology
'truncated' mean is used (for some reason unclear to me).

Here is an illustration. I generate 100 numbers from a Poisson
distribution with mean 5. Then I append five more numbers (noise)
that tend to be much larger, from a Poisson distribution with
mean 100. Here are four examples:

```
x = c(rpois(100,5), rpois(5, 100))
mean(x);  mean(x, trim=.05)
## 9.304762
## 4.926316

x = c(rpois(100,5), rpois(5, 100))
mean(x);  mean(x, trim=.05)
## 9.780952
## 5.273684

x = c(rpois(100,5), rpois(5, 100))
mean(x);  mean(x, trim=.05)
## 9.352381
## 5

x = c(rpois(100,5), rpois(5, 100))
mean(x);  mean(x, trim=.05)
## 9.485714
## 5.431579
```

In the last example, the sorted data (105 observations, before trimming) are as shown below. Numbers in brackets show the index of the first number in each line.

```
  [1]   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
 [22]   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   5   5
 [43]   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6
 [64]   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
 [85]   7   8   8   8   8   8   8   9   9   9   9   9  10  10  10  11  80  90  98 102 108
```

In  this particular type of example, there are usually five large 'noisy' observations and the trimmed mean usually ignores all of them. Even so,
the trimmed means tend to be a little larger than 5 because the lowest 5%
(mostly 0's and 1's) is also ignored. So there is a sense in which the
large numbers still have an indirect effect.

In 100,000 simulated examples of this type, ordinary means averaged 9.52, trimmed
means averaged 5.20. Also, the trimmed means were somewhat less variable
than the ordinary means.

From what you say, it is not clear to me whether you want 'means' that
are somewhat influenced by the noise, or whether you want to try to
essentially eliminate the noise.

Comment: I want to eliminate the noise. However I am not able to identify anything as noise. E.g. my dataset could look like this:

{255,245,235,50,0,1,0}

Obviously in this case 50 is the one only real Noise point. However as the overall "mean" will automatically lie near to the average (as 50 does as well). Therefore It seems not too important to handle noise points in between these two peaks.
So: Yes I want to eliminate the noise but a perfect value is not too important and that is why I prefer a fast solution over a clustering approach or similar things. I guess Ill give that solution a try.